# List files in a Google Drive Folder in Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-sites

I am following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites), specifically in Section 2.

This bit of code snippet is giving me problem

```js
function showFolderInSite() {
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById("PASTE_FOLDER_ID_HERE").getFiles();
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("PASTE_PAGE_URL_HERE");
  var listItems = page.getListItems();
  for(i in listItems){
     listItems[i].deleteListItem();
  }
  for(i in files){
     var title = "<a href=\""+files[i].getUrl()+"\">"+ files[i].getName() +"</a>";
     // Add data according to the order of columns in your list
     page.addListItem([title, files[i].getType(), files[i].getSize(), files[i].getOwner(), files[i].getLastUpdated()]);
 }
}
```

The error I have encountered is

```
The anchor tag supplied for the List Item was not properly formed. (line 13)
```

When I change the code to

```
var title = "<a href=\"File"+i+"\">"+ "DEBUG: File " + i +"</a>";
```

The script runs properly and the list on Google Site page is updated - obviously with "DEBUG" for the name and an invalid link. I can actually see the correct Type and Owner, though not for the other columns.

What could be the issue here?

URL is https://sites.google.com/site/startupgaragemalaysia/file-list

Comment: I can't recreate this error with an image file in a drive using your exact same code. What is the filetype you're trying to do this with? I've tried with an uploaded image and a Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it runs without problems in my environment. I created a Listpage with a list with 5 columns. Just ensure you have the first column of the list set to type URL and the last column of the list to date.

-- Update: I had it run on another folder. This folder had files in it with '&' symbols and some other symbols that need to be URL encoded. So you'll have to do something like encodeURIComponent(files[i].getName())